# How to run this sql query with RIA

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, c#-4.0, ria

i written this sql query and my environment is using RIA, Object Context in Domain Service Class to load data by default. but now i not sure how to retrieve and dump it into generic list structure of below

```
public class LectAllInfo
{
    public DateTime StartTime {get;set;}
    public DateTime EndTime {get;set;}
    public string Venue {get;set;}
    public string Purpose {get;set;}
}
```

Generic List Content

May i know how should i write the code to withdraw the data from object context with RIA and dump into list ? Thank you for reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a stored procedure mapped to a 'function'.

- Create a stored procedure which returns your data.
- Update your EF model (`Update from database...`)

  - Add the stored procedure to the model
- Right click on the EF designer and choose `Add function import...` (it's one of the top options), which will open the function import dialog.
- Enter the name that you want the function to be called, and the return type. The easiest way is to click the button at the very bottom ('show columns' or something) and then choose `Create new complex type`. A class will be created that contains a result of the stored procedure.

Now you'll have a function on your `ObjextContext`, named according to the choices you made. You call it very simply:

```
var result = objectContext.MyStoredProcFunction(a, b, c);
return result;
```

Comment: Thx and sorry for didn't tick your's reply as correct answer while both are correct but he reply first.. anyway, sincere thx for reply =D Cheer ^^

Comment: Thx =D This answer right to the point and solved my problem =D

Comment: @SLim Put your cursor over the function name and it will tell you the return type. Or write `return result.ToList();` and then it will be a list.

Comment: because i want to dump into data grid and i nested your result call into this few line 
public IQueryable<LecAllInfoResult> LecAllInfo(string lecId)
        {
            return this.ObjectContext.LecAllInfo(lecId).AsQueryable();
        } 
but i failed to call up from silverlight apps, anything goes wrong ??

Comment: Do you know where is the problem for this call ??

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that returns the query result and then 
call this stored procedure in your app

Check [RIA Services - call a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756434/ria-services-call-a-stored-procedure) in stackoverflow

Comment: can you please give me some example on how to call up this store procedure from apps or domain service ??

Comment: do you know where is the problem for this call ??